# Are questions on living history OK here?

Tags: discussion

In [this discussion on area51](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8385/70400) we argue whether there should be a living history.SE or just a SE site for one (though big) particular living history (LH) group. I was suggested to ask my LH questions here.

AFAIK typical LH questions are whether certain equipment or combat technique is appropriate for certain time, space and social strata (such as "Are these clothes [insert picture] OK for a 16th century German landsknecht?" or "Were Caesar's legionaries trained for this [insert link to youtube video of a combat scene]?"). Are such questions absolutely OK here? Or are they OK, but most people here would prefer to have some better place for them? Or can some of them be off-topic completely?

Comment: I'm alright with this as long as they don't get to localized or become NC.

Comment: I created [LivingHistory.SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/48560/living-history?referrer=Qp0wRu9YYXK8vV0yXJqjaQ2) proposal.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on how your questions is phrased, asking about whether a current costume is exact might be out of scope but asking about components of a uniform or the development of it would be within scope.  I wouldn't see them all as history questions (as a historian) and while we have some that are close to it they tend to be more in scope of the time they take place in, not whether or not something being done now is correct.  Again its the phrasing, asking about whether someone in the Society of Creative Anachronism is in the right suit of armor would be off topic, asking about the armor from the time and its evolution or if it was still in use within a century or two would be in.

Comment: I take it as "they can be phrased to pass as good questions here, but making LH.SE is definitely better in the long run."